# ¿Como puedo cambiar el tamaño de fuente del texto asignado a un checkbox?

Tags: html, css

No consigo averiguar como modificar el texto que viene como acompañamiento a mi checkbox, ya que de repente aparece enorme y por mucho que trate de modificar usando classes y dandole un font-size normal, no cambia, cuando el resto no ha tenido ninguna anomalia a la hora de migrarlo.

Como luce en comparacion al resto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const username = document.getElementById('username');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const direccion = document.getElementById('direccion');
const telefono = document.getElementById('telefono');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    checkInputs();
});

function checkInputs() {
    var usernameValue = username.value.trim();
    var emailValue = email.value.trim();
    var direccionValue = direccion.value.trim();
    var telefonoValue = telefono.value.trim();

    if(usernameValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(username, 'Introduzca un nombre, por favor');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(username);
    }

    if(emailValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(email, 'Introduzca un email, por favor');
    } else if (!isEmail(emailValue)) {
        setErrorFor(email, 'El email introducido no es valido, intentelo de nuevo');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(email);
    }

    if(direccionValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(direccion, 'Introduzca una direccion, por favor');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(direccion);
    }

    if(telefonoValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(telefono, 'Introduzca un telefono, por favor');
    } else if(telefono.value.length !== 9) {
        setErrorFor(telefono, 'Su numero no tiene la longitud adecuada');
    } else{
        setSuccessFor(telefono);
    }
}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
    formControl.className = 'form-control error';
    small.innerText = message;
}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = 'form-control success';
}

function isEmail(email) {
    return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email);
}
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

gsap.utils.toArray('.segmento').forEach(section => {
  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: section,
    start: 'top top',
    pin: true,
    pinSpacing: false
  });
});
```

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

nav {
    background-color: #000033;
    opacity: 0.95;
}

.cookie-container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #2f3640;
    color: #f5f6fa;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 16px rgba(47, 54, 64, 0.151);
    transition: 400ms;
}

.cookie-container a {
    color: #f5f6fa;
}

.cookie-container.active {
    bottom: 0;
}

.cookie-btn {
    background: #e84118;
    border: 0;
    color: #f5f6fa;
    padding: 12px 48px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.column-right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.column-left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0rem 2rem;
}

.column-left h1 {
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-style: italic;
}

.column-left p {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 1.1;
}
.column-normal{

  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:3rem;
}
.column-normal p{
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: 4rem;
  line-height: 4;
}
.column-normal .image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 750px;
  max-height:400px;
}
.container{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.segmento {
    background: #EC96D3;
}
.cuatro {
  background: #66488f;
  height: 50vh;
}
.for{
  height: 400vh;
}
section{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  position:static;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
section .container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  height:95vh;
  padding: 3rem calc((100vw - 1300px)/2);
}
section .containersp{
  display: block;
  padding: 3rem calc((100vw - 1300px)/2);
  height:50vh;
}

section .containerGAL{
  padding: 3rem calc((100vw - 1300px)/2);

}
.gallery-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 300px);
  width: 80%;
  margin: 100px auto;

}
.gallery-container .gallery-card{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery-container .gallery-card a > img{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.gallery-container .gallery-card a{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.gallery-container .gallery-card a > img:hover{
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
section .containerimg{
  display: block;
  padding: 3rem calc((100vw - 1300px)/2);
  height:60vh;
}
section .text {
  color:#fff;
}
section .image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 750px;
  max-height:400px;
}

footer {
    margin: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: sticky;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000033;
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 14px;
    flex-flow: row wrap;

}

.footer-left img {
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 60px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.socials {
    text-align: center;
}

.footer>* {
    flex: 1 100%;
}

.footer-left {
    margin-right: 1.25em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.footer-right {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.footer-right>* {
    flex: 1 50%;
    margin-right: 1.25em;
}

.box a {
    color: #999;
}

.footer-bottom {
    text-align: center;
    color: #999;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.footer-left p {
    padding-right: 20%;
    color: #999;
}

.socials a {
    background: #364a62;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .footer-right>* {
        flex: 1;
    }
    .footer-left {
        flex: 1 0px;
    }
    .footer-right {
        flex: 2 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .footer {
        padding: 15px;
    }
}

.btninicio {
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #6F1E51;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.footer h2 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.footer ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.footer li {
    line-height: 2em;
}

.footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
section .containerfrm{
  padding: 3rem calc((100vw - 1300px)/2);
  height: 150vh;


}
.form {
    padding: 30px 40px;
}

.form-control {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.form-control label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.form-control input {
    border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.form-control input:focus {
    outline: 0;
    border-color: #777;
}

.form-control.success input {
    border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.form-control.error input {
    border-color: #e74c3c;
}

.form-control i {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 10px;
}

.form-control.success i.fa-check-circle {
    color: #2ecc71;
    visibility: visible;
}

.form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
    color: #e74c3c;
    visibility: visible;
}

.form-control small {
    color: #e74c3c;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.form-control.error small {
    visibility: visible;
}

.form button {
    background-color: #051261;
    border: 2px solid #051261;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    .social-panel-container.visible {
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }

    .floating-btn {
        right: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lightbox.min.css">
    <title>Contacto</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="log.png" />
    <style>
    section .containerfrm{
      display: block;
      padding: 3rem calc((100vw - 1300px)/2);
      height: 150vh;

      background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 1000px;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .form {
        padding: 30px 40px;
    }

    .form input{
      font-size: 10px;
    }

    .form-control {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .form-control label {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .form-control input {
        border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
        border-radius: 4px;
        display: block;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .form-control input:focus {
        outline: 0;
        border-color: #777;
    }

    .form-control.success input {
        border-color: #2ecc71;
    }

    .form-control.error input {
        border-color: #e74c3c;
    }
    .check {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    .form-control i {
        visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40px;
        right: 10px;
    }

    .form-control.success i.fa-check-circle {
        color: #2ecc71;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
        color: #e74c3c;
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .form-control small {
        color: #e74c3c;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .form-control.error small {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .form button {
        background-color: #051261;
        border: 2px solid #051261;
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: #fff;
        display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

        .social-panel-container.visible {
            transform: translateX(0px);
        }

        .floating-btn {
            right: 10px;
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark  sticky-top">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SneakerReport</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="ini.html"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="histo.html"> <i class="fa fa-book"></i> Historia</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Contacto</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-certificate"></i>
                        Marcas
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="sup.html">Supreme <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="pal.html">Palace <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="segmento">
      <div class = "containersp">
        <div class="column-normal">
            <p class="text animate__animated animate__heartBeat animate_slow animate__infinite">¿Necesitas mas información?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="segmento dos">
      <div class = "container">
        <div class="column-right">
          <img src="me.jpg" alt="Levv" class="image" />
        </div>
        <div class="column-left">
          <h1 class="text">
            Bienvenido
          </h1>
            <p class="text">¡Buenas! Soy Gonzalo Canteli y un dia como hoy en septiembre del 2018 empecé ademas de mis estudios informáticos, a interesarme por la moda
              y la cultura alrededor de ella. Este proyecto es una demostración de algo grande que quiero llevar a cabo.¡Espero que te guste!

            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="segmento dos">
      <div class = "container">
        <div class="column-left">
            <p class="text">Si lo desea, puede comunicarse con nosotros a traves de nuestro <a href="#" style="color:pink"onclick="JavaScript:window.location='mailto:'+'gon73li'+'@'+'gmail'+'.com'" > email</a>

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="column-right">
          <p><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3040.6082074751016!2d-3.678305028399778!3d40.35103652134233!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0xd4226bdd9ea0d85%3A0xafc17f8fcff53d6!2sCentro%20Cultural%20los%20Rosales!5e0!3m2!1ses!2ses!4v1609434348458!5m2!1ses!2ses" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="segmento for">
      <div class = "containerfrm">
        <div class="column-normal">
          <form id="form" class="form">
                <div class="form-control">
                    <label for="username">Nombre y Apellidos</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="P ej: Juan Perez" id="username" />
                    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                    <small>Error</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-control">
                    <label for="username">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="juan@perez.com" id="email" />
                    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                    <small>Error</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-control">
                    <label for="username">Direccion</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Avenida de Andalucia 4" id="direccion"/>
                    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                    <small>Error</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-control">
                    <label for="username">Telefono</label>
                    <input type="tel" placeholder="643936483" id="telefono"/>
                    <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                    <small>Error</small>
                </div>
            <input name="aceptacion" type="checkbox" class="check"/>
            Acepto el uso de mi informacion con fines informativos
            <br />

                <button style="cursor:pointer">Enviar</button>
            <button id="boton" style="cursor:pointer">Reiniciar</button>
            </form>


        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer class="footer segmento cuatro" style="bottom:0">
        <div class="footer-left">
            <img src="yzy.png" alt="snk">
            <p>SneakerReport nace como una solucion para que gente de todas las edades tenga una posibilidad
                de acceder a moda limitada sin pagar reventa.</p>
            <div class="socials">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011277759449" target="_blank"><i class=" fab fa-facebook"></i> </a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/Gonzaacdz" target="_blank"><i class=" fab fa-twitter"></i> </a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gx.neee/?hl=es" target="_blank"><i class=" fab fa-instagram"></i> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="footer-right">
            <li>
                <h2>Paginas en las que tenemos soporte</h2>
                <ul class="box">
                    <li><a href="sup.html"> Supreme </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Palace </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>Otras secciones</h2>
                <ul class="box">
                    <li><a href="histo.html"> Historia </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Inscribete </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>Direccion</h2>
                <ul class="box">
                    <li>  </li>
                    <li> Piso 1º Puerta B </li>
                    <li> Madrid, ES, 28021 </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="footer-bottom">
            <p>Todos los derechos reservados a &copy;Gonzalo Canteli 2020 </p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <a class="btninicio" href="#"> <i class=" fas fa-angle-double-up"></i> </a>
    <div class="cookie-container">
        <p>Utilizamos cookies propias y de terceros para mejorar la experiencia del usuario a través de su navegación. Si continúas navegando aceptas su uso. <a href="#">Política de cookies. </a></p>
        <button class="cookie-btn">
            De acuerdo
        </button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script>
        AOS.init();
    </script>

    <script src="cookieplugin.js"></script>
    <script src="lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lightbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="contact.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("boton").onclick=clear;
    function clear(){
      var i;
        for (i = 0; (i < document.forms.length); i++) {
          document.forms[i].reset();
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que noto aquí:

```
<input name="aceptacion" type="checkbox" class="check"/>
Acepto el uso de mi informacion con fines informativos
```

Es que:

- El texto que acompaña al input no esta contenido dentro de ninguna etiqueta HTML, mas allá de pertenecer como un elemento mas del formulario
- La clase que le defines al input afectará solamente a este mismo y no al texto en si
- Ya que están vinculados el input con el texto, entonces como notas en este [enlace de la MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/checkbox) haremos lo siguiente:

  - Declaramos una etiqueta `label`
  - Dentro de la etiqueta anterior contenemos entonces al `input` seguido del texto
  - La clase que le des al `label` ahora si se capaz de *afectar* las propiedades del texto

**Ejemplo 1**

Este primer ejemplo no logrará modificar el tamaño de la fuente:

```html
    <style>
      #unId {
        font-size: 50px;
      }
    </style>
    <input type="checkbox" id="unId">Hola
```

**Ejemplo 2**

En este ejemplo el texto si verá incrementado su tamaño al estar contenido dentro de otra etiqueta

```html
    <style>
      #unId {
        font-size: 50px;
      }
    </style>
    <label id="unId">
      <input type="checkbox" >Hola
    </label>
```

Siendo esta última la opción que te **recomendaría** implementes

Comment: Era exactamente lo que necesitaba! Muchisimas gracias!